# numpy works well in Jupyter Notebook, but not in command line

Tags: python, numpy, command-line, anaconda, importerror

I am trying to schedule my py file in command line, it has been tested in jupyter notebook, and the ipynb file works well. But when the py file runs in command line, it shows the problem:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_np.py", line 9, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

I have investigated the problem, and found one of the similar problem from [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1413313/importerror-missing-required-dependencies-numpy), but my Anaconda3 has been installed under Users\xxx\Anaconda3. I am wondering:
1. Whether the path variables is the reason of the problem?
2. If it is, should the Anaconda3 been reinstalled under ProgramData?
3. If the path variables isn't the reason, what is the possible reason?
Thanks.

Comment: `from . import _mklinit` error looks borked; if you're using Anaconda, your `numpy` should have been compiled with MKL. Did you follow the advice on the thread you found and update anaconda?

Comment: Maybe see [this github issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10884#issuecomment-499805821)

Comment: But it works well at jupyter notebook. Is it normal? I am not sure if I update the install path, what the consequnce will be, so I would like to be cautious before making the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this problem caused by the path variables .  It has been soved by:
adding 5 variables as below to PATH variables:
\anaconda3
\anaconda3\Library\mingw-64t
\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin
\anaconda3\Library\bin
\anaconda3\Scripts